# What is the best NHibernate cache L2 provider?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, nhibernate, cpu-cache

I've seen there is a plenty of them. NCache, Velocity and so forth but I haven't found a table comparing them.

What's the best considering the following criterias:

1. Easy to understand.
2. Is being maintained lately.
3. Is free or has a good enough free version.
4. Works.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for what's best or worst, but I'll throw in my experience with NCache in case it helps.

*Disclaimer: NHibernate and I had some disagreements, we have since gone our separate ways :)*

### The Good

- The performance was great
- The support was great, it's well maintained (I'm speaking to status as of ~6 months ago)
- It has a free version (caveats below)
- It worked as well as possible, but I had issues with the base level 2 cache provider implementation...but this was a problem on the NHibernate side with HQL, not the NCache side.

### The Bad ([For reference look here](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/))

- The free version had it's limitations, they are strategically put there no doubt, but for our project ultimately we couldn't use the free version because of some key features not available. The below restrictions are on the **FREE** version.

  - Key Based Dependency is not included
  - None of the database dependencies are included
  - No 64-bit version

Those were the sticking points on 2 different projects for me...however aside from those, no problems and I was happy with the simplicity of install and configuration.  If the above aren't sticking points/requirements for you, I do recommend giving it a shot.  It took me less than 10 minutes to get a server up and functioning as our L2 cache.

Comment: I appreciate your attention Nick. Let me ask you a question: I have an object A' of type A in cache that has a collection Bs of objects of type B. If I take B'' that does not belong to Bs and change it so that it should now belong to Bs, will A'.Bs.Count change? Note A' is in cache.

Comment: @André Pena: Yes it will, provided you have the `<cache usage="read-write"/>` directly under **both** the `<class name="A">` and the `<bag name="Posts">` within it.  If you have a local copy of A and are not re-fetching A then it will not, since you are dealing with a separate copy....but if you fetch A at any point (or are adding to the local A) after adding B, it should have an accurate count.

Comment: I've got a chance to use NCache, and it was good. Nick is very right in his findings. i just to add one thing, although key based dependencies, database dependencies and no 64-bit version are not there is the express edition, but it all are present in the Enterprise and professional edition. for reference please read [edition comparison](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/edition-comparison.html) and [NHibernate L2 cache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/nhibernate_l2cache_index.html)

Comment: I am trying to decide if nhibernate is suitable. Do you mind sharing what in NHibernate you have disagreements ? Thanks.

Comment: @dan_l - A lot has changed since this answer, so my issues may no longer be relevant...but the configuration piece (you need a generator to just create the XML for any project of scale back at that point...not sure if this is still true)  Also the performance just isn't there, the same is true of Linq2SQL, you pay a large cost to get that data transformed into objects.  For example: now working on Stack Overflow, we do all new development in Dapper which is excellent from both our love of direct SQL (for tuning, etc) and a very terse method call to get your data back as fast as possible.