# what are the factors when choosing a solution for nhibernate second level caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, second-level-cache

[i see in this article, its easy to setup the syscache option](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/using-syscache-as-secondary-cache-in-nhibernate), but i wanted to see if there was a pro / con list of the other options for second level cache (memcache, velocity, syscache2, prevalence, etc . .) to make sure i am making the right choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate Cache Provider Differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805528/nhibernate-cache-provider-differences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative performance compared to other equivalent caches would be one consideration. Also whether the cache is appropriate for deployment in your app (e.g. syscache relies upon ASP.NET so would be no good in a desktop app).

Also, do you require your 2nd-level cache to be distributed or not? In that case you will need to look at an option such as Velocity that supports distribution.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137225/what-is-the-best-nhibernate-cache-l2-provider) discusses the pros & cons of using NCache.

Comment: Actually, the ASP.NET requirement is incorrect. You can use the "ASP.NET" cache in Windows apps as long as you have the full framework installed and not just the Client Profile.

Comment: Hmmm... also .Net 4.0 has the classes in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace that would be more appropriate to use perhaps.

Comment: Yes, but NH is compiled against NET 3.5. However, it's not hard to create a clone of the syscache provider using those classes (because you can still use NH in 4.0 solutions)